# OAuth2.0 returns unreachable instance_url

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, integration, oauth2, bulk-api

We've run into a very interesting (and frustrating!) problem while onboarding a customer whose Salesforce instances are on the *.cloudforce.com domains. Our app uses OAuth2 to connect with our clients' Salesforce instances and then uses the token we receive to perform various API calls (SOAP, REST, Metadata, Bulk).

During the 'complete' stage of the OAuth2 process, when our app tries to reach the Salesforce REST API at the instance_url we receive, we get an error saying the domain name could not be found. I tried looking up the domain name through dig/nslookup but didn't come up with anything. The errant domain is in .cs87.salesforce.com. Note that the client's Salesforce instance is on a .cloudforce.com domain and not .salesforce.com. We are somehow being redirected from the cloudforce domain to salesforce.

Could this be a problem with the API version we try to access? Our app currently tries to use API version 42.0. Is it possible that this version is not available on the instance we are connecting with and we thus end up getting redirected elsewhere? What is the recommended way to negotiate API versions when connecting via OAuth2?